# Document a service in PHP

Tags: php, documentation, documentation-generation

I'm writing a service in PHP. Others will access this service with HTTP GETs and POSTs and it will just return plain json. It's simple and suits the needs.

However, I would like the phpdoc I write in the PHP to show up if they visit it via their browser (i.e. without the `$_GET` variables I use to generate the result). Is there something that just parses every comment in a phpdoc-ish way and shows the results?

Edit: of course I realize I could just echo some static text, but I'm specifically looking for something that *dynamically* generates that, so it's not possible for me to forget to update the text with new calls or changed parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options that come to mind: a cron job or on-demand PHPDoc. Then have your site issue a redirect to the documentation when visited without any parameters.

Comment: If you did on-demand, yes. If you implemented it as a cron job, you could schedule it to run every x minutes (or hours) and automatically update the documentation.